# output of bidirectional_dynamic_rnn?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using bidirectional_dynamic_rnn to deal with classification task for variable length of sentences. Here is a part of my code:

```
lstm_fw_cell=rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
lstm_bw_cell=rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
lstm_fw_cell=rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_fw_cell,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_rate)
lstm_bw_cell=rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_bw_cell,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_rate)
outputs,_=tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell,lstm_bw_cell,inputs=self.word_embeddings,sequence_length=self.text_len,dtype=tf.float32)
output_rnn=tf.concat(outputs,axis=2)
```

The shape of `output_rnn` is (50,100,200) which is (batch size, max_length, 2*hidden layer size). Because I used zero padding to all sentences, in this case, the short sentence has been padding to 100 words. The `text_len` is a list of length for each batch. I hope `output_rnn` remove the zeroes, only output the last layer. for example, sentence 1 has 35 words, so the output only calculate 35 words, sentence 2 has 72 words, so the output only calculate 72 words, sentence 3 has 21 words, so the output only calculate 21 words, and remove the 22 to 100 words which are all zeroes. how to do this?

I used `self.output_rnn_last=output_rnn[:,-1,:]` but in this case, it calculate the 100 word, which are zeroes, I hope to calculate the value based on the sequence length.